# How to Add existing Scene to VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, scene

Every .blender, file that we save, is a SCENE in itself, right? So the VSE provides a option to add a Scene. Now after adding the scene, how can I link it to an existing Scene?

For example : 
1. I create a 3d Text and save it as Text.blender. 
2. Now I create a video using the VSE and save it as Video.blender.
3. To Video.Blender I add a SCENE.
4. How can I link the New SCENE to Text.blender?

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 1):

A ".blend" file is a an entire project that consists of 1 or more scenes.

A .blend file can have a scene dedicated to VSE output.

Any .blend project can "Append" another .blend's scenes.

[image: append scene]

[image: scene navigation]

[image: scene selection]

Navigate to the required .blend project and select the Scene category.

Once you have appended or "imported" an external scene it is available to add to the timeline (shift-A) in the first .blend file's VSE scene as a scene strip.

[image: add scene strip]

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.93 (perhaps earlier) you simply create a VSE-scene (call it 'master' or similar) and any number of other VSE-scenes containing the different video-clips. You can then add each scene as a strip, and set each scenestrips input to 'Sequencer'

[image]

There seems to be some difference in contrast (or some other image-parameter) between an original VSE-scene and a VSE-scene imported as a strip. I have yet to find out why that happens. But if you colorgrade your individual scenes, they will not look exactly like your grading when you import them as strips. **EDIT: Further testing shows, that the colors seems to be unaltered. I must've had some difference in settings between the two scenes. Right now it seems to work as intended**

**Tip:** if your changes in the original scene does not show up in the imported version of the scene, mouseover the sequencer-area in the masterscene and hit SHIFT+r which will refresh all strips.